# You are not authorised to use this service iTunes app upload error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, app-store-connect

Since the Apple "Users & Roles" update to iTunesConnect end of november 2015 some people have been experiencing an error message "iTunes Store operation Failed" and "You are not authorized to use this service".

This happens when using XCode 6 and 7

[image]

Previously i was able to upload app using the same iTunes account.

Comment: what if you try app uploading through xcode organizer  ?. I know its not the answer of your problem but you will get the app uploaded

Comment: I am uploading app from Organiser and when i try to upload the app using App Loader also getting the same error

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you find the cause? I can log in to itunes connect fine. Started happening this week.

Comment: @EdSykes I created the ipa using Xcode 6 and save to my mac and upload that ipa using App Loader 2.9.1.

Comment: I've tried this several times without any luck. It seems totally random as I was able to validate an app earlier today and now I can't even validate or submit without getting this error. Super frustrating!

Comment: @NicholasJohnMartin I'm facing the same issues for a couple of hours today, I'm about to get mad! I decided to skip validation and I used Application Loader to upload my binary to the App Store. It doesn't show the same errors, I could upload it this way.

Comment: @Vive, you are 59 reputation points away from being able to reopen the question if my understanding of how that works is correct. Unfortunately, it will be quite a while until I have enough rep to vote for it myself.

Comment: @AlexeyVMP (and anyone else debating whether this should be closed.) A question that attracts 12 different answers (+5 more deleted) is definitely broad. If it wasn't broad, there would be ONE answer, or answers would be slight variations. But the described condition could be the result of many different problems. So, it should be closed so no more answers can be added, and then optionally rewritten to be more specific. That doesn't mean it's not helpful. While it should be closed, it doesn't need to be deleted. **If you really feel strongly**, then edit the question to improve it!

Comment: I know this is an old question but here is the issue that caused this error for me. I had an admin role on the developer.apple.com but I didn't have any roles on iTunes connect account.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally i am able to upload the ipa to the iTunes store.

First of all i create ipa using Xcode 6, Export for iOS App Store Submission. Save on my mac.

And upload ipa using Application Loader version 2.9.1. And it was successfully uploaded to iTunes.

May be It will help someone.

Comment: Uploading the build using Application Loader worked for me. Strangely, this issue is occurring with only one of my projects. I don't know what's the reason.

Comment: Same here. Had to use Application Loader which actually pointed to an error in my archive (I had not supported all interface orientations). After I fixed that, it uploaded just fine. Note that Xcode *could* have been helpful in this case, but it just failed with a generic, unhelpful  authentication error message. Will keep using Application Loader for quite some time now instead of uploading the app via Xcode!

Comment: **Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader**. That's it.

Comment: This is the solution for desperate ones. The solutions above is known by the developer who does code signing several times but this is the was the last resort for me and it worked. God damn Apple's app singnig process.

Answer (score 59):

I had the same issue today. What I did is mentioned below.

```
Go to XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Apple Ids
```

From that select your Apple ID, remove it, and then add it again. Quit Xcode, open it again, and then clean and archive the project.

It worked for me.

Hope it works for someone else also.

---

**EDIT**

If your Apple ID is already there you can also try with refresh button for all provisioning profiles and certificates.

Then restart Xcode, clean and build the project. You'll be good to go!

Comment: I just saw this error. Xcode had plain lost my account info.

Comment: Bingo, I was registered with @ me not @ icloud. Xcode wanted to use @icloud. Good call.

Comment: Yes, it will also work if you have not changed your apple id details. In that case just refresh the provisioning profiles and certificates and restart your xCode and clean and build. You will be good to go then.

Comment: Will you please clarify what you mean by "you can also try with refresh button for all provisioning profiles and certificates"?

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein: There is a refresh button when you go to xcode->preferences and in accounts, there is a refresh button at the left bottom side. Please try to refresh it.

Comment: Somebody in London loves you. You just saved my holidays. YOU ARE AWESOME!!!!!!!!

Comment: This did not work for me (XCode 7.2). I had to use Application Loader to upload my app to the App Store.

Answer (score 44):

On Xcode 7.1 I disabled **bitcode** during the submission and it uploaded perfectly.
[image]

EDIT: You can also export your app archive (iOS App Store Submission) and use Application Loader (press choose button and locate your export file). There is no "Include bitcode" option, so my Guess is it's off by default in Application Loader.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue for me too. Never would have guessed from the error message.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well.  Does anyone have any idea how to get this working with the bitcode enabled?

Comment: Same here with Version 7.1 (7B91b). Only two options: upload without bitcode or through Application Loader. Sad to see how Apple treat devs...

Comment: Using Application Loader I was able to respond to a warning regarding "Potential Loss of Keychain Access" while uploading for a client transferred app. I was able to obtain more information, and respond accordingly. This allowed me to successfully complete the upload.

Answer (score 10):

I know it is an old question, but maybe I noticed something that it might help you.

Today when I try to login to **Itunes Connect** via browser, Apple returns me a message "*Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly.*" , but I'm sure that my id and pass was correct . It seems apple side problem, not ours.

I think that there is something that it doesn't work in Apple, and it is **not** an Xcode bug.

I don't know why they don't warn anyone about that.

**EDIT**

Now *Apple* updated its [System Status - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/).

Comment: I just tried, with a Team member, and then with the Team agent... I accepted the updated Agreement with Team agent. Both didn't work

Comment: I tried too but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: Same here, maybe it will work again in a few hours...

Comment: Not to spam, but I'm having this issue too. I think people should know that it is an Apple issue before going crazy about trying to fix it themselves.

Comment: It seems that now Apple updated the System Status page.

Comment: I can log in to iTunes Connect now, but still have this issue uploading an ipa. Hopefully this will fix itself soon..

Comment: Same here. Website login works, but i cant upload ipa.

Comment: It does not matter how old the question is if the phenomenon is still occurring. It sporadically happened to me today.

Answer (score 10):

I experienced the same error when I was working from overseas and had a very slow internet connection (upload speed).  In my case it had nothing to do with the credentials or refreshing of the profiles.  It was just the upload speed.  I had an upload speed of less that 1Mbps.  I attempted multiple times without success.  Then I went to a restaurant where the upload speed was 11Mbps and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I had similar issue. I have used Application Loader instead and it went through... let's see how the Processing will finish.

Comment: Application Loader uploads the binary even if the speed is less than 10KB/sec. And using Application Loader was surprisingly easy.

Answer (score 3):

You selected developer account which don't have rights to publish. Make sure that you selecting correct one.

On the picture:
1. Is the agent account.
2. Member account without rights to publish.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing this issue last week. But that was due to iTunesConnect outage but now apple solved that issue and server working fine so you will not experience this issue. Please check and hope that will work now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete your account on Xcode Preferences Accounts
2. Close Xcode
3. Add Your account again
4. Archive
5. Submit

Answer (score 1):

I got this error today when trying to upload from Xcode 6. The app I tried to upload was developed for another customer, but I was admin on their account. But, now my personal Apple Developer Subscription has expired. I'm still admin on the clients account, so I could login, validate builds, download provitioning profiles, etc, but when I tried to submit I got the error described above.

My solution was to remove my own Apple Id and instead login using my clients Apple Id directly.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your Apple ID from xocde and add it again, make sure you quite beta Xcode if you have opened, then open it again, clean, archive, validate, it works for me

Comment: It's good to talk about 'beta Xcode', because it seems that beta versions of Xcode are not allowed when you are trying to submit an App. What I mean is that if you use a beta version of OSX or a beta version of Xcode the error will be shown, and it is pretty confusing. I explain it because it took a lot of my time to be aware of how having a beta version of OSX blocked the submission of an App in a non-beta Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Log out of the application loader, then sign back in.

Happened to me and was banging my head against the wall for hours with different combinations of signing...

Comment: you can try to use Application loader instead of using Xcode directly.
For example i had you same problem and I do not receive any logs except the one you wrote... When i used Application loader I understood the true error.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a wrong provisioning profile (old one) when hitting this error.

Just go member center and download current provisioning profile for AppStore distribution. Double-click to install and make sure that this profile is used when building the app.

[image]