# App Submission on iTunes error

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store, app-store-connect

When i am trying to upload app to the app store using Xcode 6, 
I am getting the error

> You are not authorised to use this service.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem which I couldn't resolve, so I uploaded the app with **Xcode 5.1**, and it worked.

Comment: yes, its working on Xcode 5.1. i think some it is bug in Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this previous answer:
[You are not authorised to use this service iTunes app upload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error)

It doesn't work for me though and I'm trying to find another work around.