# iTunes store operation failed: You are not authoried to use this service

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes-store

I successfully submitted my app a few days ago and waited for a review, however I found a bug in my app later, therefore I rejected the submission and fixed it. But when I try to validate the app, Xcode shows me an error:

> iTunes store operation failed: You are not authorized to use this service.

I also tried submit and export options, it shows the same error.

I googled it, someone else also met this error and posted it in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error), then tried the solution:

re-login -> quit Xcode -> open Xcode -> clean -> archive -> validate

it didn't work.

FYI:

Xcode 6.1.1

The code signing identity in target's building settings is `iOS Distribution` as well as the one in project's building setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue today and I believe it is due to an iTunes Connect outage as I was also unable to log into iTC via the web.

You can check the service status of Apple's Developer Services on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/).

You can also do a quick search on Twitter to discover any other users who are having login issues with iTunes Connect.

Comment: Me too. I hope it's an apple problem.

Answer (score 11):

My Apple ID as a dev is different than my iTunes Connect Apple ID.  I exported the archive to an iOS App and then used Application Loader to upload it using the ITC ID.

Comment: I keep running into this problem. I setup apps for clients and they have the same login for both dev account and ITC. This is becoming really annoying!

Comment: You may have to wait a few minutes for ITC to recognize the Build uploaded via the Application Loader.

Answer (score 2):

Some days ago I also meet this same problem, I tried many thing but no result.

After that I tried this,

- First archive the app with xcode 6.
- Export that build from xcode 5 organizer.
- Upload the build from xcode 6 application loader i.e. 3.0 version of application loader.

Try this steps, it may help you

Comment: I don't have xcode5 after updating to xcode6, maybe I should download it

Comment: If Export is also not working in xcode 6 organizer then download it

Comment: I have export it by xcode6, but the application loader showed me an error:`We’re having trouble connecting to the App Store. Please try again later. ` `You are not authorized to use this service.`

Comment: ok, then download xcode 5 then try

Comment: I've archived and exported it with xcode 6 and uploaded it with the newest application loader ... works for me. But I also have this problem since yesterday.