# Issue submitting archive to IOS Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have tried submmitting my app through xcode 6 and application loader 3 and keep getting the same error.

itunes store operation failed "you are not authorised to use this service"

I uploaded an app 2 days ago with the exact same profile with no such problems. Has anybody encountered this issue before ? It is extremely frustrating as there is nothing that i can change to get past this.

I have tried logging out of my apple id in xcode and signing in again but this did not help. I am the only one on the provisioning team and have full rights to upload this app as i used this profile just 2 days ago to do the same thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

David

Comment: Check your certificates. Its expired or not.?

Comment: [the same issue here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error

best wishes!

Comment: I have checked and both certificates are up to date and all provisioning profiles are valid, and thank you for the link but i have been through thread and the issue is still there unfortunately.

Comment: Uploading to app store is like trial and error method..keep on trying..try to generate a new provisioning profile and use it

Comment: are you the team agent?

Comment: Yes i am the team agent.

Comment: Regarding the provisioning profile, i am told that it signs the app fine but the error comes after that when i try and validate or submit the app. It happens during the "uploading app" phase.