# You are not authorized to use this service for provider

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

[image]

I'm not really sure if this is something with iTunesConnect or not.  Uploading an archive results in an error.  The error mentions a name no one here heard of, possibly some ID issue confusion on apple part.

I tried restarting, cleaning project, removing Apple ID and adding it back in... same result.  It's similar to the error here... (No one heard here of Ryan, so probably some iTunes weirdness)

(tried solutions from link below, didn't work)
[You are not authorised to use this service iTunes app upload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error)

Comment: Yeah it definitely sound like a credentials issue. Go to your developer.apple.com > member center > Identifiers > and ensure that your App ID or Certificate has not expired. If it has, create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using XCode app loader, you can still use legacy one.

To do it:

1. Archive your app normally
2. Open Organizer, select created archive, press "Export..." on the right. Leave "Save for App Store Deployment" selected, press "Next"
3. Answer export questions, at the end you will get folder with exported .ipa file
4. Now, launch app loader from XCode menu: "XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader"
5. In Application Loader click "Deliver your app" icon
6. Press 'Choose' in the right bottom, select previously exported .ipa
7. Follow upload steps

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7, a simple restart fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use someone's other's code? Try to search for this name in your project, because some developers forget to remove their Code Signing settings before publishing open source projects.

Comment: No one like that ever worked or existed here.  That's why that error looks so odd.  We really are not sure where is Apple getting this "Ryan" from.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well. I have a lot of different credentials for different portals, and I think something was not working properly on Apple's end (or in the latest XCode), because I usually have no issues when submitting an app.
I worked around it by using the old 'Application Loader' app to submit my work to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I have met this problem these days.I'm using Xcode 7.1 (7B91b).I have tried may methods for this.I thought there is something wrong with my certificate or provisioning settings.You can pay attention to the following settings;

`Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Choose your account -> View Details`

[image]

Pay attention to the Action, some may show create,and then you create it.But this is not working for me.

At last, I have uploaded by the ***Application Loader***

[image]

.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to submit app to AppStore the role of your iTunes id need to be either "Agent" or "Admin".