# Xcode 7.1 - Not authorized to use this service Error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, tvos

I did a fresh install of OSX on my machine yesterday and installed Xcode 7.1. After having signed in with my developer account and fixing all code signing issues that come along, I wanted to upload my tvOS app.

Important to say that I did not change a single line of code in the app.

Each time I try uploading it, I get "You are not authorized to use this service" and I can't proceed.

[image]

I also tried all the steps described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error) to solve it without success.

Does anyone have the same issues? Is it Xcode, iTunesConnect or tvOS App Store not fully enabled yet?

Comment: I had some weird Xcode permission issues with downloading docs. Deleting and re-adding my Apple account info solved it.

Comment: I tried deleting and re-adding account (along with various other fixes mentioned in linked question) but still get the same error on Xcode 7.1 with tvOS app. (Have had no issues on Xcode 7.1 with another account and iOS App.)

Comment: Having been trying over and over again... and eventually one attempt worked fine (didn't do anything special for this) but then the next c. 10 attempts (with a slightly updated build) have gotten the same "not authorized" message.

This suggests to me something is not working properly at Apple's end rather than it being something we are doing 'wrong'... might be worth coming back to this after a day or two?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, finally figured out something that worked (all of the certificate issues etc turned out to be irrelevant; though frustratingly it did work 1 time (out of about 30) from within Xcode Organiser which meant I kept trying:

- Do the usual Product -> Archive thing
- In Organiser click on the "Export..." button
- Choose "Save for Apple TV App Store Deployment"
- Export that
- Now from Xcode Menu (*not via spotlight etc*) choose Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
- Verify this is version 3.3 (not 3.0 which won't work)
- Click on "Choose"
- Pick the IPA you have just exported
- Follow submission process

Hopefully Apple will sort out whatever issues are going on with Organiser soon.

Comment: OSX Packages have the same problem, and the same solution works! Thanks!

Comment: Solved my iOS app submission problem too.

Comment: I don't know if this really is the problem, but I had the same issue until I opened up Application Loader and accepted the license agreement there. Since then it seems to be working correctly right from Xcode. That would make sense in the context of the "not authorized" message.  Come on Apple...

Comment: This solution worked like a charm couple weeks ago, but today when I want to submit a tvos archive, it just does not work... "You are not authorized to use this service" all the time. Really frustrated

Comment: Application uploader started to work for me again after I turn off 2-step verification for my apple id, not sure if that is the root cause, but it is worth trying if the solution does not work

Comment: The uploading via Application Loader worked also for Unity game build.  Thanks. upvoted.

Comment: That's the solution, all the others are blabla... It's a shame, but without Jobs all the amateurs back again...there is no iTunes upload without a new nonsense error message. This is Apple quality??? C'mon!

Answer (score 7):

I tried several recommendations I've seen around Stack Overflow, and the Apple Forums. This includes deleting every single one of my Apple accounts from Xcode, restarting and then adding them back again (what a pain! I have 15 dev accounts!) Unfortunately for me, none of those options worked.

The only thing that **did** resolve this behavior *for me* was to use Application Loader to upload my binary to the store. That worked without any issues.

For those unfamiliar with Application Loader, you simply build your app as normal and archive it to the Organizer. Then export the binary for App Store distribution. Then import that generated .ipa file into Application Loader and follow the process to upload it to the store.

Comment: Application Loader tells me that I am "missing required field: In-App Purchase"... appears to be no way of using it without In-App purchases.

Comment: Okay, so importantly need to click on the "Export..." button in Organiser and then use Application Loader with Exported ipa.

However, that didn't work for me; now seeing: 

ERROR ITMS-90545: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not compatible with iOS apps." 

There is some speculation on Apple forums about using the same bundle id on both iOS and tvOS Apps being source of problem.

Comment: @James then that definitely indicates that you have some sort of provisioning profile issue at-hand. The best bet would be to ensure that you have selected the proper profile and signing identities for both the project and the target and try again. This is a secondary issue to your original post.

Comment: Thanks. That particular issue I got round by using the Xcode bundled Application Loader (3.3) rather than the version Spotlight opened (3.0).

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to restart XCode (7.2) and try again for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just got an email today that Apple TV apps can now be submitted. Before, I was getting the *"You are not authorized to use this service"* error but today I no longer get it.

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll try submitting it in a bit and let you guys know if that was it :). Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Looks like deleting my Apple ID and putting it again after restarting Xcode didn't do anything. Using the Application Loader, the build appeared in iTunesConnect, however.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What I did to get past it was pretty drastic though...

- I restored an old computer with El Capitan and the new Xcode.
- Transferred the private keys across to the machine.
- Created an .ipa for exporting.
- Uploaded to iTunes Connect using Application Loader

The computer I was using could still upload the iOS app without any issues. Its possible there's some remnants of the Beta Xcode lying around.

It seems that uploading to App Store for Apple TV is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had same weird Xcode permission issues with my universal app(not iwatch) ,I solved it by disabling the bitcode from build setting.So try following steps.

- Go to build setting
- Build option
- Enable bitcode
- set Enable bitcode to NO
- create a new IPA and upload.

It will work