# Archive validation failed - not authorized to use the service for Provider

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit the iOS build to appstore from app manager role. But i got a error  "you are not authorized to use this service for provider:".

[image]

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error

Comment: actual reason the some one used the same bundle identifier on another project , please check once

Comment: actually this is the version update of the project which is already in app store. We have updated this verison with icloud & document picker.

Comment: else try in app loader once to upload the app