# Error uploading .ipa file with Application Loader

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, ipa, application-loader

I have exhausted all ideas and read every SO post related to this issue but continue to get the same error.

I have a `.ipa` file downloaded from Phonegap that I'm attempting to upload to the App Store with Application Loader but I continue to get this error:

> You are not authorized to use this service for provider: KC5935S3JJ

The only thing that is unique about my situation is that I'm on a team deploying on behalf of our company.

Things I can ensure:

- team admin and have all roles checked in iTunes Connect
- production certificate for signing with option App Store and Ad Hoc
- distribution provisioning profile with option App Store
- cert and provisioning profile created for team admin Apple ID
- uploading with Application Loader using team admin Apple ID
- app and new version created and configured on iTunes Connect

Things I've tried:

- signing in/out and restarting Xcode and Application Loader
- regenerating certs, provisioning profile, and `.ipa` file multiple times

Potentially useful details:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.2
- Xcode 8.2.1
- Application Loader 3.6

[image]

Comment: check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't lying when I said that I'd read every post on SO about this issue. I tried everything recommended in that thread to no avail.

Comment: have you upload it with out application loader try to upload from Xcode remove account in team and add account again

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Cordova with Phonegap to generate the `.ipa` so it is not a project in Xcode

Comment: contact Phonegap team and iTunes with error number mention above, they will be able to guide you further.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your team/provider. You're aware that you need 2 separate invites for Apple Developer center and iTunes Connect? What happens if you try to login with your Apple ID (the one you try to upload with) to iTunes Connect? Does everything look normal?

Comment: @AmodGokhale, I'm afraid that's what I will have to do, although I'm pretty sure the issues is purely on Apple's end.

Comment: @Oddie, that was the conclusion I came to too.  I'm aware of that and have received both invites and have made sure I'm taking actions in the Developer center and in iTunes Connect on behalf of the team.  When I log into iTunes Connect everything is normal.  I can see the app and the new version I've created.